# Byobu custom widget messes up my status bar

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, byobu

I wrote a very small byobu widget, put it in ~/.byobu/bin/, named it correctly (e.g. `60_widget.py`); I opened Byobu, pressed F9, enabled the "custom" status notification and saved it.

Now the widget is in my status bar, and all the colors are reversed. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with the version of byobu packaged for Ubuntu 12.04. This is fixed somewhere in between Byobu 5.17 and the currently latest version of the software, Byobu 5.57.

You can head to the [project page](https://launchpad.net/byobu) to grab the latest version (e.g. `apt-add-repository ppa:byobu/ppa && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`). You won't even have to restart your session to enjoy the fix.

Comment: Many thanks to kirkland of irc.freenode.org/#byobu for helping with this.